# Full Log in Aggregation - Open Distro

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-opendistro, wazuh

I want to know how I can put the full log from the event in aggregation, because the full log is not a field. I know how I can put, for example, the agent.name, but full log, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Amy.

Thanks for using Wazuh.

The full log is added as part of the aggregated information, and can be used as part of a filter if you go into an agent's events and add it as filter. It will allow you to select a specific instance of full log you want to select.

[image: Here]

In the picture above, you can see a picture of the dashboard where I am selecting the full log as filter.

I hope this clears your question.
Cheers,